# how to Alert integer values in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, alert

How can I alert an integer value in flex. I have a variable called total which is an integer.

If I try to alert it using

```
var total:int=myTest.length;
Alert.show(total);
```

it throws an errors saying that

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type int to an unrelated type String.
```

the show method accepts only string values. How can I alert this int value?

Actually, what I want is to know the value stored in the total variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Alert.show(total.toString());
```

[reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/int.html)